# Set Dynamic height of a tableview cell

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a collection view under a table view cell. I show all the tag values in the collection view. Now I want to make the height of the table view will dynamic so that I can show all the data. The user does not need to scroll the collection view.
I use auto-layout in my project. Currently, I return "UITableView.automaticDimension" in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) method and make collection view scroll property false.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To make the `UITableView`s height = to the content of the tableview, you can use the `table.contentSize.height` property. See the following,

1. Since you are using autolayout, create an `@IBOutlet` for your tableview height constraint.

```
@IBOutlet var tableHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

2. When you update the table set the content height as the new value for the `tableHeightAnchor.constant`

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    self.tableHeightAnchor!.constant = tableView.contentSize.height // Setting new height
}
.
.
.
tableview.reloadTable()        // If you are reloading your tableview 
self.viewWillLayoutSubviews()  // This is required
```

3. Next, you can set the height of the cells based on the height of the tableview.

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let height = tableview.bounds.height
    return height/items.count
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have multiple cells in that table view and the collection view is in section 0 index so I think this answer will not work for this situation

Comment: You might want to correct your question because it is a little misleading. So you want the collectionview to have a dynamic height?

Comment: Yes, I want collectionview to have dynamic height